# Yii2 SELECT * WHERE id = array()?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

i has Query select use WHERE = array(1,2,...), i tried IN but only data of the end ID and previous ID's data does not appear. Help me, thank for all.

My code:

Controller:

```
public function actionGetServiceType($q = null, $id = null) {
        \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        $out = ['results' => ['id' => '', 'text' => '']];
        if (!is_null($q)) {
            $queryTest = new Query;
            $queryTest->select('service_type_id')
                ->from('link_service_group_all')
                ->where(['IN', 'service_group_id', $id]);
            $query = new Query;
            $query->select('id as id, title AS text')
                ->from('service_type')
                ->where(['like', 'title', $q])
                ->andWhere(['IN', 'id' , $queryTest]);
            $command = $query->createCommand();
            $data = $command->queryAll();
            $out['results'] = array_values($data);
        }
        return $out;
    }
```

Comment: `$queryTest` is not an `array`... you'd need to execute that query first and then use the result.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Can you describe more specifically

Comment: You only execute the second one query, but not the first one ...it should be obvious.

Answer (score -1):

```
public function actionGetServiceType($q = null, $id = null) {
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $out = ['results' => ['id' => '', 'text' => '']];
    if (!is_null($q)) {
        $queryTest = new Query;
        $queryTest->select('service_type_id')
            ->from('link_service_group_all')
            ->where(['IN', 'service_group_id', $id]);
        
        $queryTest = array_values($queryTest->createCommand()->queryColumn());
        
        $query = new Query;
        $query->select('id as id, title AS text')
            ->from('service_type')
            ->where(['like', 'title', $q])
            ->andWhere(['IN', 'id' , $queryTest]);
        $command = $query->createCommand();
        $data = $command->queryAll();
        $out['results'] = array_values($data);
    }
    return $out;
}
```

you were missing a line like this

`$queryTest = array_values($queryTest->createCommand()->queryColumn());`